# Get Microsoft Edge Browser Version using registry or command line

Tags: microsoft-edge

How can i get microsoft edge browser version using registry or command line?
I don't want to take it from UI.

Answer (score 4):

The older answers to this question seem to address [Edge Legacy](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/what-is-microsoft-edge-legacy-3e779e55-4c55-08e6-ecc8-2333768c0fb0) to the exclusion of [Edge Chromium](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/microsoft-edge-chromium-1ce9507c-f09d-4de6-a706-eb52f46be90c) (which is now standard). Adding this answer to more fully outline current options targeting Edge Chromium, specifically.

## Windows via Registry

For Windows systems, reading the Edge version from the registry is probably your best bet, since it's consistent even when the installation path varies. Some command-line for reading the installed version of Edge Chromium from the registry. There are a few options for that.

### Using Powershell:

```
(Get-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Edge\BLBeacon -Name version).version
```

### Using Powershell and [Windows Script Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/admin-development/create-desktop-shortcut-with-wsh):

```
(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell).RegRead("HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Edge\BLBeacon\version")
```

### Using [Reg Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg-query):

```
reg query HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Edge\BLBeacon /v version
```

## Windows via Executable

If you have more than one instance of Edge installed (for example, an Edge Dev Channel build) and you want to get the version of a specific installation, you can access the VersionInfo metadata of the Edge executable.

### Using Powershell:

```
(Get-Item "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge Dev\Application\msedge.exe").VersionInfo.FileVersion
```

### Using the [WMIC tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmic):

(Note that escaping is required when translating the EXE path into the WMI query)

```
wmic datafile where 'name="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge Dev\\Application\\msedge.exe"' get Version
```

## Non-Windows via App Binary

For non-Windows installations, running the binary from your shell with the *--version* flag seems to be the best bet. Your path may vary.

### Ubuntu example:

```
/usr/bin/microsoft-edge --version
```

### Mac OSX example:

```
/Applications/Microsoft\ Edge.app/Contents/MacOS/Microsoft\ Edge --version
```

## Via Package Managers:

Especially on Linux installations, where Edge is likely to have been installed using a standard package manager, version querying via package management is also a solid option.

Note that this option does only apply if the Edge installation is under package management, which is pretty uncommon in non-Linux userland.

Using [apt](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/apt.8.html) (Ubuntu):

```
apt list microsoft-edge
```

Using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) (Mac OSX):

```
brew info microsoft-edge
```

Using [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) (Windows):

```
choco list -l microsoft-edge
```

Answer (score 3):

For [Microsoft Edge Legacy](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4533505/what-is-microsoft-edge-legacy), you can get the version from PowerShell with Get-AppxPackage:

```
> (Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge).Version
44.18214.1000.0
```

If you want to call this from cmd.exe, you can just call Powershell:

```
> powershell.exe "(Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge).Version"
44.18214.1000.0
```

Comment: `(Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge).Version` would be a slightly more compact way to do it.

Comment: Just tried this. Looks like Edge is version displayed in `edge://settings/help` is 84.0.522.44, but command `(Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge).Version` returns 44.18362.449.0 instead.

Comment: @Fusion clarified that this answer covers Edge Legacy rather than the current Chromium based Edge browser

Comment: @gsnedders Yeah, I saw that, but I wonder why this command returns any value at all, even if clearly Chromium based Edge browser is installed. Does it have some wierd backward compatibility stuff by default?

Comment: @Fusion I believe Edge Legacy is always installed; EdgeHTML at least is a system library and used by third-party applications, and I believe they haven't fully unbundled the two. They have primarily just prevented Edge Legacy from starting as a standalone browser unless a given registry key is set.

Answer (score 3):

### In Windows

> The first of all, you need to get the path of the .exe file of the application.

#### use `Get-Item`

It is just like `Get-AppxPackage`. And get the version by adding `.VersionInfo`.

```
> (Get-Item "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe").VersionInfo

ProductVersion   FileVersion      FileName
--------------   -----------      --------
85.0.564.63      85.0.564.63      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe
```

#### use `wmic`

`wmic` can get the information of the application. And we set the `name` key for which application you want to check.

```
> wmic datafile where 'name="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe"'

AccessMask  Archive  Caption                                                       Compressed  CompressionMethod  CreationClassName  CreationDate               CSCreationClassName   CSName           Description                                                   Drive  EightDotThreeFileName                                         Encrypted  EncryptionMethod  Extension  FileName  FileSize  FileType     FSCreationClassName  FSName  Hidden  InstallDate                InUseCount  LastAccessed               LastModified               Manufacturer           Name                                                          Path                                              Readable  Status  System  Version      Writeable
1179817     TRUE     C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe  FALSE                          CIM_LogicalFile    20200924185451.733609+480  Win32_ComputerSystem  DESKTOP-QCUDFJL  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe  c:     c:\program files (x86)\microsoft\edge\application\msedge.exe  FALSE                        exe        msedge    2882448   Application  Win32_FileSystem     NTFS    FALSE   20200924185451.733609+480              20200928200140.091076+480  20200923164851.469016+480  Microsoft Corporation  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe  \program files (x86)\microsoft\edge\application\  TRUE      OK      FALSE   85.0.564.63  TRUE
```

And then, filter the result by adding `get {key}` at the end of command.

```
> wmic datafile where 'name="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe"' get version

Version
85.0.564.63
```

### In MacOS

#### use `--version`

The application is executed from `/Applications/"Microsoft Edge.app"/Contents/MacOS/"Microsoft Edge`. Therefor, we can command like the bottom.

```
$ /Applications/"Microsoft Edge.app"/Contents/MacOS/"Microsoft Edge" --version
Microsoft Edge 85.0.564.63
```

Answer (score 2):

Run the following command:

```
REG QUERY HKEY_CLASSES_root\AppX3xxs313wwkfjhythsb8q46xdsq8d2cvv\Application /v ApplicationName
```

Example output:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AppX3xxs313wwkfjhythsb8q46xdsq8d2cvv\Application
    ApplicationName    REG_SZ    @{Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_40.15063.674.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe?ms-resource://Microsoft
.MicrosoftEdge/Resources/AppName}
```

Now you just need to extract the version, e.g. the `40.15063.674.0`.